# My beanstalk tube has 344 current-jobs-ready and current-jobs-urgent

Tags: beanstalkd

I'm having an issue where there are

current-jobs-urgent: 344

current-jobs-ready: 344

I checked it 10 minutes later and it is still at 344.
Does this mean my Beanstalk is backed up?

Comment: It means you don't have any worker setup correctly to process them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you don't have any worker setup correctly to process them.